# visualize classifier prediction, scatter

Tags: python, matplotlib, classification, scatter

I would like to plot a scatter plot like this, where you can see the wrong predicted and true predicitons of a classifier including the numbers of the predicitons

[image]

i tried with this scatter plot till now

```
predictions_rf = rf.predict(X_test)
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
plt.scatter(Y_test,predictions_rf)
plt.xlabel("True Values")
plt.ylabel("Predictions")
```

and i got a scatter plot like this:
It is possible to see the wrong estimated ones as well but not diagonally and not with the numbers the model predicted right and wrong

[image]

How could I improve my code to get a solution like the first one?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to plot is a confusion matrix.

Sklearn's confusion matrix described [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_confusion_matrix.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-confusion-matrix-py) does exactly what you're looking for.